# Wireless Connection not working

Tags: wireless, connection

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04-1 on an HP Pavilion V-4000 laptop.  The wireless does not work and doesn't show any wireless networks.  There is a switch to turn on wireless, but now it doesn't work. It worked just fine when running windows XP. Please advise how to get this working.

Thanks

Comment: can you get a network connection through the Ethernet port?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes HP laptops have this dumb slider on the front edge or on one of the sides. If you can't find the slider check to see if you have a function key on the top row of your keyboard that has a wireless symbol on it. This is another common way to switch the radio on and off. If after trying to find the switch give the steps below a try.

I had an HP laptop that did the same Thing.

I had to install this wireless package to get it up and working.

[bcmwl-kernel-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bcmwl-kernel-source)

you can install it by opening a terminal window and running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Once it has installed go ahead and reboot your PC and when the system is booted up check the wireless menu.

Note: if you did hit any switches to toggle the wireless try and toggle them again. wait about 10 secs between presses to make sure it has enough time to come up.